# LVM volume falsely reporting itself as full

Tags: lvm, disk-space-utilization

I am standing up a new CentOS 6 system to do some data processing.  As I load the data into a brand new 100gb LVM volume, I reach about 35% full, and it starts to report that there is no space left on the device, for both user accounts and for root.  I do not see anything new being written to either dmesg or /var/log/messages when I attempt to write more data.  I am rather at a loss on what can cause this behavior without writting anything to logs.  This persists even after a reboot, and lsof reports no open files on the mount point. du and df agree on how much space is used on the volume.

Any advice on how to figure out why I cannot use the other 66% of the volume would be greatly appreciated.

When I run
touch /srv/data/test
(/srv/data is the mount point) I get the error message:
touch: cannot touch `/srv/data/test`: No space left on device.

Per one of the comments below, I see from df -i that I am out of inodes. I will have to research how to deal with a lack of inodes.

Comment: Can you explain what is saying its full, and also provide an output of `pvs`, `lvs` and `pvs` along with a `df -h` or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes error messages are a little misleading, and could report "disk full" or "no more space" when you still have space but have actually run out of free *inodes*.

Check that with the `df` utility and its option:

```
  -i, --inodes          list inode information instead of block usage
```

Comment: This command shows the problem, I am out of inodes.

Comment: for those looking for a solution to full inodes: `mount -o remount,inode64 /srv/data`

Comment: @OttoV the `inode64` option is not a generic mount options, it's an XFS specific feature. On `ext2/3/4` (and possibly other filesystems) the maximum inode quantity is determined at `mkfs` time and it _cannot be changed_ on an existing filesystem. The OP says he's using CentOS so he's probably using XFS, but he could have chosen a different filesystem for that particular volume.